# Create acroform in pdf with free software?

Tags: pdf

Which free software/open source alternatives are there for adding an acroform to a existing pdf, creating a fillable form?

I have a list of alternatives on http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-tools-for-generating-interactive-pdf-forms/, but which would you recommend?